# How to use a decorator to send arguments to a function in python

Tags: python, python-decorators

I have a set of functions in python that gets the same 2 parameters + other parameters.

```
def myMethodA (param1, param2, specificParm)
    do code

 def myMethodB (param1, param2, specificParm1 specificParam2)
    do code
```

I waned to create a decorator that replace the need to call with the first 2 parameters by pushing the parameters before calling the function:

```
@withParams()
def myMethodA (specificParam)
        do code
```

But if I omit the parameters then the decorator can't call it either and if I leave them then the caller need to specify them as well.

anyway to solve this?
Can I do something with args* but still have named parameters for specificParam?
Also, How can I reference param1 and param2 inside myMethodA

Comment: Take a look at `functools.partial` too

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It sounds like you may want `functools.partial`.  It returns a new function with some parameters already specified:

```
import functools

def withParams(func):
    return functools.partial(func,1,2)

@withParams
def myMethodA (param1, param2, specificParam):
    print(param1,param2,specificParam)

@withParams
def myMethodB (param1, param2, specificParam1, specificParam2):
    print(param1,param2,specificParam1, specificParam2)

myMethodA(10)
myMethodB(12,13)
```

> ```
> 1 2 10
> 1 2 12 13
> ```

Comment: This looks great but how does `myMethodA(10)` works if the signature is myMethodA (param1, param2, specificParam)?

Comment: Both options solve the problem and both can be used. I picked the partial since the syntax is cleaner

Comment: That's what a decorator does. Assigns a new function object to the function name. In this case the new function takes two fewer arguments and calls the original function with the two provided parameters plus any additional.

Comment: @EranWitkon Anyway, I think Marktolonen answer is a great fit. +1

Answer (score 0):

You can add those two parameters when you call the function in the decorator's wrapper function as part of the `kwargs`. All decorated functions will automatically have those two parameters passed as keyword arguments before making the call:

```
def withParams(func):
    def wrapper(*args, **kwargs):
        kwargs['param1'] = 1
        kwargs['param2'] = 2
        return func(*args, **kwargs)
    return wrapper

@withParams
def add(specificparam, *args, **kwargs):
      print(specificparam)  # 3
      print(args)           # (4,)
      print(kwargs)         # {'param2': 2, 'param1': 1}
      return specificparam + sum(args) + sum(kwargs.values())

print(add(3,4)) # 10
```

You can drop the `args` part if all you'll be passing from the main function call are the *specific parameters* for each function.

Comment: This what I was hopping but isn't decorator just a function call? How would adding two parameters to a function that doesn;t expect them would work? I would expect to get something like ' method expected 1 parameter but 3 supplied

Comment: Also, in this way, I can not reference param1 and param2 in myMethodA as they are not defined.

Comment: @EranWitkon You could use `*args` in your function to collect `param2` and `param2` with the other arguments. See update.

Comment: Yes, this is good but I wanted to still have the specific params with explicit names.  `def add(spesificParm1 spesificParam2, *args, **kwargs):`

Comment: @EranWitkon That's assuming `param1` and `param2` can come after `specificParam2`but remember you stated they were positional arguments right? OTOH, you could define `param1` and `param2` as keyword arguments.

Comment: Yes, that is OK in this case. Supper Helpfull

Comment: @EranWitkon If you update your question with these requirements, I can improve the answer to fit them :)

Answer (score 0):

I'd recommend you go old school, and just reassign the names using [`functools.partial`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functools.html?highlight=functools.partial#functools.partial):

```
# module foo

def func1(common_1, common_2, specific_1):
    pass

def func2(common_1, common_2, specific_2, specific_3):
    pass
```

Then elsewhere (or lower in the file, if you like) you can do this:

```
import functools

import foo

common_args = (1, 'fred')
foo.func1 = functools.partial(foo.func1, *common_args)
foo.func2 = functools.partial(foo.func2, *common_args)

# ...

foo.func1('special')

foo.func2('equally special', 'but different')
```

Answer (score 0):

Sounds like you need `functools.partial`, to pre-populate the "constant" parameters:

```
>>> from functools import partial

>>> def myMethodA(param1, param2, specificParm):
        print("myMethodA(", param1, param2, specificParm, ")")

>>>> def myMethodB (param1, param2, specificParm1, specificParam2):
        print("myMethodB(", param1, param2, specificParm1, specificParam2, ")")

>>> preMethodA = partial(myMethodA, "p1", "p2")
>>> preMethodB = partial(myMethodB, "p1", "p2")
>>> preMethodA(34)
myMethodA( p1 p2 34 )
>>> preMethodB(8, 9)
myMethodB( p1 p2 8 9 )
```